# Nothing is being returned? Can I not assign a two-dimensional array all the values of a pre-existing one?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, initialization, point

I am trying to return an array of points by looping through an existing two-dimensional point array. findMatches(b) contains an array of arrays of points from a board. If I could just access and alter these points directly so as to return them all to the point array I am returning, that would be great, but I don't suppose it is that easy.

Here is my code:

```
public static Point[] findPossibleSwaps(Board b) 
    {
        Point[][] nums = new Point[findMatches(b).length][];
        nums = findMatches(b);
        Point[] foundSwaps = new Point[3]; 
        int xH = 0;
        int yV = 0;
        int index = 0;
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        for(int a = 0; a<nums.length; a++)
        {
            Point [] lop  = nums[a];  
            for(int h = 0; h<lop.length; h++) 
            {
                Point qo = new Point(x,y);
                qo = lop[h];
                if(qo.x!=0)
                {
                    xH = qo.x-1;
                    foundSwaps [index] = new Point(xH,qo.y);
                    index++; 
                }

                if(qo.y!=0)
                {
                    yV = qo.y-1;
                    foundSwaps [index] = new Point(qo.x,yV);
                    index++;
                }

            }

        }   
        return foundSwaps;
    }
```

Thanks everyone

Comment: Please post code here; not in an **image** on another site.

Comment: I would but I couldn't get the formatting to work.

Comment: Edit question, paste code in bottom, highlight code and press ctrl-k.

Comment: Okay, I just added it!